# Swift: get arbitrary info from UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift

I have a list of images within a cell, within a `UITableView`. For reasons I won't go (too much) into, I can't use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to know which one was selected due to the fact that I am using a third party module that adds its own parent Gestures, and I cannot set `cancelsTouchesInView = false` (which could technically fix my problem).

In either case, is there a way to add arbitrary info to a view, so that when I receive it in as the `sender`, I could introspect it.

Eg: if this were HTML & JavaScript, you could do this.

```
$(myImage).data('foo', 'bar')
$(anotherImage.data('foo', 'thunk')

$('img').on('click', function () {
  console.log($(this).data('foo')) // could be "foo" or "thunk"
})
```

In Swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  var cell = MyCustomTableViewCell()
  cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
  let tapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("myCallback:"))
  cell.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)


  // my imaginary world...
  cell.foo = self.extraData[indexPath.row]

  return cell
}

func myCallback(sender: AnyObject?) {
  println(sender.foo)
}
```

Obviously, the above doesn't work, but is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I personally don't recommend using that much but you can make use of [`objc_setAssociatedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_setAssociatedObject) if you want to attach extra data to objects at runtime.

Here is one good resource about how to do it in Swift:

http://nshipster.com/swift-objc-runtime/

---

Alternatively, UIView classes have a property named `tag` to where you can assign `indexPath.row` for getting the cell that was tapped on later:

```
cell.tag = indexPath.row
```

BTW, you better not be working on cells. Instead, always operate on its `contentView` property when you want to add gesture or another sub view etc.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    // Always remove previously added tap gestures because cells are reused
    // as you scroll up and down so you'll end up having multiple 
    // recognizers on the same cell otherwise.
    for recognizer in cell.contentView.gestureRecognizers {
        cell.contentView.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }

    cell.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(
        UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "myCallback:"))

    cell.contentView.tag = indexPath.row

    ...
    return cell
}
```

It is fairly straightforward to get the cell in call back function:

*(Presuming you have only one section so that indexPath.section = 0)*

```
func myCallback(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.view.tag , inSection: 0)         

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        print("Cell \(cell) has been tapped.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! That worked like a charm. Also, any reason not to set the gesture recognized on a cell? It worked fine in my example (meaning, I got the callback).

Comment: I think it would still work even if you set recognizer on cell too. However, it is a good practice to always work on `contentView` instead of cell itself according to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/contentView)

Comment: Sorry. Didn't know I could do that yet. I'm fairly certain users with <= 200 they can't accept an answer for a few days